# How to delete Oracle DB Relics after uninstall

Tags: database, windows, oracle, permissions, uninstallation

I've recently installed an Oracle DB on my Windows 10 Pro Laptop for testing purposes. Since the performance was horrible, I uninstalled it but can't get rid of 2 Files: cwallet.sso and ewallet.p12

Manipulationg the File Permissions as usual has not worked.

How to delete these Files?

[Image of the 2 Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkEAy.png)

Comment: what error do you get ? those files are from the wallet

Comment: [Check](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4316358https://community.oracle.com/thread/4316358) this link

Comment: Simple Windows Dialogue: Not enough permissions

Comment: @Sam the Link you've provided shows up as moved or deleted.

Comment: Looks like they're migrating to to new platform.Take the ownership of the folder or files.

Comment: @Sam I tried to do so via (German Menu Items freely translated) Windows Properties Dialogue => Security => Extended => Owner; It says you have to close the dialog and reopen it to see the changes and after doing so it says Owner can not be displayed.
Even in Secure Mode; 

Do you know a different way that may work?

Comment: You need to go to security tab and give full control to local user or Login into Administrator account(by default administrator account is hidden do google search how to activate) delete the file or boot up laptop into safe mode and delete or download [lockhunter](https://lockhunter.com/) freeware

Comment: Another option from elevated command prompt try to rename files and delete.If WSL Ubuntu installed from elevated command prompt bash terminal remove files with force.

Comment: Lockhunter did the trick for me. Thanks a lot